# Getting Digits from twilio Gather

Tags: node.js, express, twilio

I am trying to get the digits entered into phone. I thought res.Digits in Pin function would be the way but I get an undefined error

```
exports.Say = function(req, res)
{
    var resp = new twilio.TwimlResponse();

    resp.gather(
    {
        action:'http://pap-papdemo.rhcloud.com/api/Phone/Pin',
        finishOnKey:'#',
        method:"POST"
    }, function()
    {
        this.say('Please enter your Phone and Pin number followed by the hash key');
    });

    //Render the TwiML document using "toString"
    res.writeHead(200,
    {
          'Content-Type':'text/xml'
    });

    res.end(resp.toString());

};




     exports.Pin = function(req, res)
        {
            var resp = new twilio.TwimlResponse();
            console.log("***** PIN *****");


            console.log("Pin: Response " +  res.body.Digits);

            //Render the TwiML document using "toString"
            res.writeHead(200,
            {
                  'Content-Type':'text/xml'
            });

            res.end(resp.toString());

        };
```

any idea what I need to do as I need to store pin number in db

Comment: I see the Digits is in request parameters so tried req.params.Digits but didnt work

Comment: I got the answer eventually var pin = JSON.stringify(req.body.Digits);

Answer (score 1):

Megan from Twilio here. I saw you answered your own question but figured I'd update as an answer for others who land here.

[Twilio will pass `Digits` as a parameter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather#attributes-action-parameters) in addition to the standard TwiML Voice request parameters with its request to the 'action' URL.

Thus `var pin = JSON.stringify(req.body.Digits);` worked in this case.